# How to prefix a word in a list number

Tags: html, css, html-lists, pseudo-element

So I've searched high and low and have been unable to find an answer for a *seemingly* simple problem.

I have an ordered list like this:

```
<ol>
  <li>Some text here</li>
  <li>Some more text here..</li>
  <li>Oh yeah, here's some pretty text</li>
</ol>
```

Which displays:

> 1. Some text here
> 2. Some more text here..
> 3. Oh yeah, here's some pretty text

What I'd like to really display:

> Step 1. Some text here
>
> Step 2. Some more text here..
>
> Step 3. Oh yeah, here's some pretty text

**Question:** Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about doing it without using questionable solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prefix ordered list item numbers with a static string using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568229/how-can-i-prefix-ordered-list-item-numbers-with-a-static-string-using-css)

Comment: @wmeade unfortunately, it's not :-( that particular solution prefixes the text within the `li` with the letter, not the actual *number*.

Comment: I modified that answer a little and got this https://jsfiddle.net/4ok1Lxmo/.

Comment: @wmeade would you mind writing an answer so I can accept it please.

Comment: No worries, Dippas answer covers the same, so feel free to grab his.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `::before` (`:before` for IE8)  and `counter-reset/increment`

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: number;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  counter-increment: number;
}
li::before {
  content: "Step " counter(number) ".";
  position: relative;
  left:-5px
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Some text here</li>
  <li>Some more text here..</li>
  <li>Oh yeah, here's some pretty text</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Is there any way to make the "Step N" prefix bold?

Comment: Just add `font-weight:700` in the last rule of the snippet `::before`