# how to create multiple html ordered lists with different headers (edited)

Tags: html, css

I would like to create an ordered list like the one below. I appreciate your help.

---

We first collect the following equipments:

Equipment 1: Driver's license.

Equipment 2: Credit card.

Equipment 3: Laptop.

Equipment 4: ...

Then we check the car in the following steps:

Step 1: Check under the car for obvious leaks. Driving with leaking fluid may cause failure of the steering, brakes or radiator.

Step 2: Check the tires for proper inflation and any obvious damage or signs of excessive wear.

Step 3: Ask someone to stand behind your car to check the lights.

Step 4: ...

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568229/how-can-i-prefix-ordered-list-item-numbers-with-a-static-string-using-css/5568259#5568259) seems to be what you are looking for and [here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/ericrasch/NUJJk/) to go along with it

Comment: While it can achieved using CSS but again support on ie will be trouble. Why do you want it on client side. You could generate it on the server using loops? I am not able to appreciate the use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try

```css
ol.step {
  margin-left: 0;
  counter-reset: list 0;
}

ol.step > li {
  list-style: none;
}

ol.step > li:before {
  counter-increment: list;
  content: "Step " counter(list) ": ";
  float: left;
  width: 3.5em;
}

ol.equipment {
  margin-left: 0;
  counter-reset: equipment 0;
}

ol.equipment > li {
  list-style: none;
}

ol.equipment > li:before {
  counter-increment: equipment;
  content: "Equipment " counter(equipment) ": ";
  float: left;
  width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<h2>List 1</h2>
<ol class="equipment">
  <li>Driver's license.</li>
  <li>Credit card.</li>
  <li>Laptop.</li>
</ol>
<h2>List 2</h2>
<ol class="step">
  <li>I would like to create an ordered list like the one below. I appreciate your help.</li>
  <li>Check under the car for obvious leaks. Driving with leaking fluid may cause failure of the steering, brakes or radiator.</li>
  <li>Check the tires for proper inflation and any obvious damage or signs of excessive wear.</li>
  <li>Ask someone to stand behind your car to check the lights.</li>
</ol>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3z7y7vjr/5/

Comment: It looks great. Now suppose I have two list of this kind in a single webpage. The first list has Step 1, Step 2, Step 3,... and the second list has Part 1, Part 2, Part 3,.... How should I proceed?

Comment: It works the same or you can simple create two classes like: ol.list1 and ol.list2. I have updated the answer

Comment: I meant there are no hierarchical relation between two lists and these two lists follow one after another.

Comment: check this: https://jsfiddle.net/3z7y7vjr/4/

Comment: Looks great and let me check.

Comment: answer updated. please check

Answer (score 1):

All you would have to do is set up an ordered list like this:

HTML:

```
    <ol>
      <li>Step 1: Check under the car for obvious leaks. Driving with leaking fluid may cause failure of the steering, brakes or radiator.</li>
      <li>Step 2: Check the tires for proper inflation and any obvious damage or signs of excessive wear.</li>
      <li>Step 3: Ask someone to stand behind your car to check the lights.</li>
      <li>Step 4: ...</li>
    </ol>
```

CSS:

```
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  }
```

But make sure in your CSS (whether it is your style tag in the `<head></head>` section or on a separate style sheet) that you add the `list-style-type: none` attribute, because that will remove the numbers on your list.

Comment: I mean I want these counters for Step 1, Step 2, Step 3,... automatically countered.

Comment: Oh. As far as I know, I don't believe that you can do that. I could be wrong, but I don't think that that is possible. Sorry  :(

Comment: how can I have the usual ordered list and this type of list in a single webpage?